# Где делать редирект?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5

Всем привет! Мне нужно проверять что если у пользователя не заполнены данные то отправлять его на страницу заполнения. На какую бы он страницу не перешел, то должен быть перекинут на страницу заполнения данных. В каком месте нужно делать редирект? Я пробовал делать с помощью слушателей, но видимо слушатели идут один за другим и из-за этого не редиректит. Проверку сделать проблем не составляет, но вот не понимаю где надо делать эту проверку и редирект?
Не хотелось бы делать проверки в каждом контроллере, а только в одном месте

Comment: Можете, например, добавить функционал наследовав https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.0.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php и собственно метод onAuthenticationSuccess

Из токена заберете юзера, проверите его данные и если что то не устраивает  можете использовать httpUtils и редиректить куда хотите.

Comment: @zalex разве этот метод сработает не только после авторизации? В вопросе есть уточнение "На какую бы он страницу не перешел, то должен быть перекинут на страницу заполнения данных". Я так понял что пользователь не может перейти по ссылкам если данные не заполнены

Comment: Все верно, только после аунтефикации. Я предположил что у вас есть пользователь только данные не все заполнены.  Тогда не очень понятен вопрос. Если у вас нет пользователя, то куда вы собираетесь его перекидывать ? Просто на регистрацию ? Если у вас пользователь не аунтефицирован, то если у вас закрыто файрволом правильно , то система автоматом пошлет его на аунтефикацию. И как вы предполагаете проверять данные, если вы не знаете  что это за пользователь ? А если знаете, то не вижу проблему в том что я вам ответил.

Comment: @zalex на сколько я понял вопрос, то пользователь уже зарегистрирован и залогинен, но данные профиля не заполнены, например адресс и т.д. Но это нужно уже чтобы автор уточнил. А вот мне интересно что делать если мои догадки верны? Создание слушателя request и прерывание с помощью установки ответа?  `$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('...'));`

Answer (score 0):

Я позволю себе оформить ответом.

Вот что пишут в [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events), а именно мы говорим про Events происходящие при аунтефикации (аунтификации? Как правильно ?). Нужно не забывать что аунтефикация происходит при каждом запросе, но в зависимости от типа этой самой аунтефикации мы видим те или иные события. По  сему в вашем случае я подозреваю что достаточным вариантом будет повесить слушателя на событие `security.authentication.success` и делать выполнять свою логику.

Вот что по поводу этого события в документации -

> But beware - this event may fire, for example, on every request if you have session-based authentication ...

Как видите это то что вам нужно. При каждом запросе вы сможете делать проверку и возвращать RedirectResponse.

upd:
  Ну и не забывайте про очередность выполнения слушателей. В случае ежели у вас что то на этом событии висит раньше, чем выполняется ваш код, то до вашего кода может не дойти, тогда вам нужно повысить приоритет вашего слушателя. Но скорее всего вы с данной проблемой не столкнетесь.

Answer (score -3):

С целью создания редиректа, программа на PHP начинает отправлять в HTTP ответе, HTTP заголовок называемый header-ом. При помощи вызова функции до начала любого вывода данных (echo(), var_dump(), print_r() и т. д.).

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/another-page.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Вы вообще вопрос читали?